# How to make Azure OpenAI Service use default system message in API calls?

Tags: openai-api, azure-openai

I have created an Azure OpenAI Service and set a default system message. I want to create a chatbot by sending API calls to the endpoint and integrating it into an existing React App as a component.

My aim is to allow other team members to modify and fine tune the system message and examples. However, whenever I call the OpenAI Service through API Calls, I must always send the system message and examples with the request. It seems that the API responses disregard the system message unless I send it with the request.

I assumed that the default system message gets saved to the deployment and I would not have to send it on every request. Is there a way to configure the Azure OpenAI Service to always use the default system message that is configured in the Azure OpenAI Studio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current 'state of the art' does not support that, as it works on the basis of stateless interaction. What you can do is place a system prompt in a variable and include it in the OpenAI SDK call, or you can build a facade class around it. This makes it part of a class's default prompt, especially useful if you're leveraging it from multiple places, ensuring it's not 'forgotten'.

Comment: sure, that's something I thought of too. The problem with this approach then is that I have to have the system message inside of the configuration of the app or elsewhere, where other people responsible for fine-tuning the data do not have access to. And don't get me started if I want to have an external data source too. I would have to send it with every request. Do you have any experience with azure bots? Would having the bot service as a proxy help?

Comment: In that described scenario, you could create a proxy service and enforce the communication with the Azure OpenAI model through it. Not sure how exactly that would be leveraged from the use-case point of view, as on one hand you would resolve the problem of having a common prompt for all users, but on the other side, you might have work around the eventual latencies. So you would resolve one problem, but potentially introduce another one, that requires different mitigations. Maybe implement asynchronus calling, scaling etc.